# nested for loop challenge

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested-loops, primes

In this program `j` value is always 0. Why?

I try to find prime between 0 to 100. Prime numbers are in `prime` array and non primes are in `notPrime` array. While I execute this program, I was stuck in nested for loop. I try to console.log(j) the j value always 0. Why?

```
const n = 100;
const prime = [];
const notPrime = [];
if (n > 1) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    // console.log(i);
    for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
      console.log(j);
      console.log(j);
      console.log(i,j);

      if (i % j === 0) {
        prime.push(i);
        break;
      } else {
        notPrime.push(i);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
} else {
  alert("enter the lagrest number");
}

console.log(prime);
console.log(notPrime);
```

Comment: if you are not sure what your code is doing, try to replace the values manually like if you were executing it, to understand better what it is doing. 
In Javascript, you can make use of the console to execute partial parts of your code, when you don't know what's the expected result.

Prints are also very useful, but adding some text before the prints, rather than just printing the values, makes it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You're always breaking out of the loop on the first iteration:

```
if (i % j === 0) {
  prime.push(i);
  break;
} else {
  notPrime.push(i);
  break;
}
```

...so there's never a chance for j to reach anything larger than zero.

You'll need to rethink your logic quite a bit for this to work. If you find a divisor for a given number, you know immediately it's not prime, so can break the loop.

But to find out if it *is* prime you have to continue checking the rest of the potential divisors before you can be certain, so need to continue that inner loop.

1 and 0 are not potential divisors, for obvious reasons, so your inner loop should start at 2.  Anything larger than `i / 2` can also be safely skipped, because it's not possible to evenly divide anything into a larger chunk than "half".

```js
const n = 100;
const prime = [];
const notPrime = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  // we're checking to see if i is prime. Assume it is until proven otherwise:
  let isPrime = true;

  // check for divisors:
  for (var j = 2; j <= (i / 2); j++) {
    if (i % j == 0) {
      // found a divisor, so we know i is not prime
      isPrime = false;
      break;
    }
    // note there is no "else" clause here.
    // you need to finish the inner loop before you can be sure it's prime
  }

  // now we've checked everything so can record the results for i:
  isPrime ? prime.push(i) : notPrime.push(i) ;
}

console.log(prime);
//console.log(notPrime);
```